# Faking multitenancy via host file

Tags: iis, multi-tenant, hosts

I am trying to simulate multitenancy for testing purposes on my development PC via the hosts file.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 test1.gwd.nl
127.0.0.1 test2.gwd.nl
```

When I run my website (MVC4, clean new website just to figure this bit out) and navigate to URL test1.gwd.nl:50401 I get the following error:
Bad Request - Invalid Hostname

Googling it actually tells me that this should be possible.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why is this tagged as C#? Nothing in your question is related to the language.

Comment: yeah fair enough. removed it. it's writting in mvc4 but I know that has nothing to do with it either.

Comment: Did you configure the site on your IIS to bind to this host name?

Comment: @Wiktor, Humpf, no I did not. Nor do I have any clue how that works. I just run the website from Visual Studio. I have not touched IIS so far

Comment: This is why it doesn't work. Move your site to iis and configure site bindings by adding all these host names. Built in app server works only for localhost domain.

Comment: Then I'll start by installing iis :). thx so far i'll let you know how that turned out. if that's the answer to the question, then drop it as answer (even it's a bit lame, i know, but maybe there are more idiots like me)

Comment: hmm, there is no way of achieving this by internal webserver or via built in iis express support? if I go for IIS I will have to run VS with admin privileges and it doesn't make debugging and stuff easier. Is there no easier alternative? I only want to have the possibility to simulate multitenancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be:

1. Go to iis, create a new site and point to a folder where your app is located
2. Remember to add priviledges to the folder to IIS_IUSRS so that iis can access the folder
3. Configure the app pool to use corresponding version of the runtime
4. Create bindings to your host names
5. Go to your web app properties in iis and set the iis as the runtime host also point to one of your multi tenant urls as startup address

This way you debug your app with vs but the app is hosted by iis so you can easily debug multi tenancy.

Comment: Your steps help me to get started. Google will teach me the rest :). Thanks a lot!